# Jenkins: JDK configuration

Tags: java, jenkins, settings, config

I have both java 1.7 and 1.8 installed in virtual cent OS. I installed Jenkins and it is running fine but I dont know which version of java it is using. How I can detect that?

What is the configuration file of Jenkins to setup JDK version manually?

EDIT: 
** I dont want to configure JDK from **Global tool configuration** of **Manage Jenkins**

Comment: http://www.studytonight.com/jenkins/configuring-jdk-in-jenkins

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, determine the process id of your Jenkins (e.g., with `ps aux | grep jenkins`)

Then **check the corresponding `exe` entry in the `/proc` file system**:

```
$ ls -l /proc/2884/exe 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user users 0 Aug 24 08:08 /proc/2884/exe -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/bin/java
```

For *selecting* the Java version, it depends on how you start Jenkins. If you start from command line, then a proper setting of `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` will be sufficient. If you use a service file (`/etc/init.d/jenkins`, or some `systemd` approach), then this depends on the implementation of the service.